# How to get a group of objects from Firebase?

Tags: ios, database, performance, firebase, react-native

In my React-Native app, I have an array of specific users whose values I want to pull from Firebase. What is the most efficient way to go about this? Currently I am looping through the array and making a new request for each (relevant code below):

```
const usersRef = new Firebase(`${ config.FIREBASE_ROOT }/users`)

for (var key in usersArray) {
     var userRef = usersRef.child(key);
     //do stuff here
}
```

However, I feel this isn't very efficient and it makes several requests to the database. Is there a way I can pass in the array and get those items from Firebase, all in one call? Thanks.

Firebase data structure:

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "description" : "fuzzy socks",
    "type" : "toy"
  }, {
    "description" : "bouncy ball",
    "type" : "toy"
  }, {
    "description" : "scrabble",
    "type" : "game"
  }, {
    "description" : "construction paper",
    "type" : "crafts"
  } ],
 "users" : [ {
    "itemList" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
    "description" : "brown",
  }, {
    "itemList" : [ 5, 6, 7 ],
    "description" : "green",
  }, {
    "itemList" : [ 8, 9, 10 ],
    "description" : "blue",
  }, {
    "itemList" : [ 11, 12, 13 ],
    "description" : "yellow",
  } ]
}
```

Simplified use case: In one use case, I only want to get information about 2 of the users (out of all the users I have stored in Firebase--assume it's many more than just the 4 in the structure above). So, I have the array `importantUsers`:

```
var importantUsers = [0, 3]
```

Then, I want to send a request to Firebase that only queries the database for the values associated with these userID values (so somehow pass in the array to Firebase for a result). Return values would be something like this:

```
0: itemList: [1,2,3,4], description: brown
3: itemList: [11,12,13], description: yellow
```

My motivation for querying the database for multiple users at once (rather than creating a separate ref for user 0 and user 3) is to not have multiple calls made to Firebase. Is there any way to go about this?

Comment: Can you post your Firebase data structure? Please post as text (no images). The text can be obtained from your Firebase dashboard->Export button.

Comment: @Jay just updated with this.

Comment: When you say 'an array of specific users whose values', what defines them as a user, what makes them specific and what value are you interested in? In your Firebase structure there's a users node and then an array of dictionaries which contain key value pairs of itemList(which is an array) and description, neither of them being a user. Are you asking how to access a specific item list *within* the array that's in the users node?

Comment: Ah no, so in my case I only care about pulling data for a specific subset of users (say, users with id 0 and 1). So I have an array [0,1], and I want to grab only that information in one query. I guess similar to a SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE user_id= (items in array). How could I obtain that result?

Comment: Go it. So, that's not going to happen with that structure. First thing is that generally speaking, array's are evil. They're super hard to work with as you don't have access to specific elements within the array and unless you know a path, query'ing them is challenging at best. Second thing is that storing user id's as numeric values can be problematic. Leveraging the users uid will make it work much better in the long run. Last thing is that AND query's are not directly available in Firebase. Do you want to retrieve nodes where userId is say, 9, the blue one in this case?

Comment: Yeah, I guess my main question was whether or not AND queries are available in Firebase. Thanks for the tip on uid's as well. I know how to get nodes of individual userIds by modifying the ref path. Then in this case if I only need data for certain users, would it be more efficient for me to pull all the users from Firebase and then loop through the IDs I want, or make a separate request for each specific user ref that I care about? The former provides me with a lot of data I don't need (and could take a very long time depending on length of user list) but the latter is more requests to the db

Comment: I think if you could update your question with a use case - specifically what data you are after and how it's related to users we may be able suggest a Firebase structure and code to make that work.

Comment: @Jay just updated my question. Please let me know if it is unclear.

Comment: It's getting more clear. In this updated question, you want to get data about two users, 0 and 3. What is the correlation between those two users. Both have descriptions of 'brown' or is there some other correlation? How to those users relate?

Comment: In this case they have nothing related in the database except my app needs both their data (the array [0, 3] is formed via a function that just returns random user IDs). Overall I want to be able to pass in a list of random user IDs and then display their data from Firebase. Is there a way to do this in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you are after is an sql 'in' type query. Select in [0,2]. To select a number of users from a list.

The additional challenge in your question is that users you are interested in are random so you can't use .startAt and .endAt, and there is no other relation between the users.

Firebase does not have direct support for 'in', 'and' or 'or' kinds of query but there are a number of ways to make it happen.

How about this: flag the users you want and then with a single query, read them in.

First, you'll start with a typical Firebase /users node with the addition of a 'selected' child node (this can be omitted initially but I am showing it here as a placeholder)

```
users
 uid_0
   name: "Bud"
   selected: false
 uid_1
   name: "Henry"
   selected: false
 uid_2
   name: "Billy"
   selected: false
```

Then, we need some random uid's, say uid_0 and uid_2 and store those in an array. Keep in mind that we would be using the Firebase generated uid but we'll use uid_0, uid_1 etc for simplicity.

With just two users, you could just observeSingleEventOfType on each of the two nodes, no big deal.

However, if we needed 100 random users or 1000, doing 1000 separate queries or observeSingleEvent's should be avoided. But, setValue is blisteringly fast (no returned data) so....

Get our users ref

```
let usersRef = myRootRef.ChildbyAppendingPath("users")
```

We know the path to each of the 100 users we want by iterating over the array to build those refs and set selected to true

```
for uid in uidArray {
  let thisUserRef = usersRef.childByAppendingPath(uid)
  let selectedRef = thisUserRef.childByAppendingPath("selected")
  selectedRef.setValue(true)
}
```

Then, you can query for all users in the usersRef where the selected child = true.

Once you have them, to clean up, iterate over the returned users and set the selected to false or nil

The cool thing about this is that setValue can blast through 100 or 1000 users very quickly with no overhead, setting their selected child to true. Then a single query can return the values you want.

Seems almost reverse in logic to write out to then read back in but I am pretty sure it's considerably better than iterating over an array and generating 1000 queries or observers.

(Firebase folks can check me on that one)

One other thought is that if a user is say, clicking on other users in a list, you could set selected = true as they are clicking and then query for those when the user is done.

Comment: This is a great, innovative solution! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [bindAsArray or bindAsObject](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/react/api.html) from ReactFire

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/items");
  this.bindAsArray(ref, "items");
```

Then you could loop over that array/object as needed without extra queries

Comment: Hmm, but won't this grab the whole list of items? I only want a subset of them, for example, items with certain IDs. Is there a way to pass in a list of the IDs I want to Firebase and only get results for those specific items?